# MFC: Save from CImage to database as selected file-type

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi, image-processing

We have a requirement that a user can load any standard image into a dialog, the image is displayed, and the image saved as a specific format (JPG) in a database. It seems CImage is the class to be using since it can load and save BMP/GIF/JPG/PNG. But is there an easy way to save the JPG as a BLOB in the database without calling CImage::Save and then loading the file to memory - we don't want to save the file even temporarily.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is exactly why i hate `MFC`, no obvious way to do obvious things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CImage::Save` has two overloads. You could use

```
HRESULT Save(
   IStream* pStream,
   REFGUID guidFileType
) const throw();
```

to save the image to an `IStream`. You could write your own simple `IStream` implementation or could try to use the `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` function, which creates an `IStream` object on an `HGLOBAL`.